# Saving the Tabs page state (Backbone View) in Javascript (Backbone)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am trying to save the state of the page across the tabs. Of the 3 tabs I have to save the state of one of the tabs say TAB-3 . In order to do this, I am planning to do the following -

1- On tabs click event, attached to the main page that has the 3 tabs, I am saving the complete div of TAB-3 in a variable (this variable is the member variable of the backbone view) that will have the page state with the latest UI changes made by the user along with the scroll position.

2- While rendering the TAB-3, I plan to check the view variable containing the state. If it exists then while rendering the backbone view the previous state saved in the variable is rendered else the data coming from the API call is passed to the template and the corresponding HTML content is then appended to the page.

I was wondering if there can there be a better approach to this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

im not quite sure if i get your entire question, but if you want to save changes made to a tab; you might want to make the tab a model and view of its own;

set the state in the model. 
these models should be in a collection.
now you can re-render the collection and it always has you states in the model.